# Struggling to get my output variable to display at the top of the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, calculator

I have been trying for a few hours now to create a basic data usage calculator where when you select one of the buttons, it calculates the value assigned and displas it at the top of the page.

You can see in the

part I am intending to display it. I will get around to the monthly data usage as that will feed from the total data usage.

Can anyone point out to me what I have wrong here? I managed to get it working fine with the values were just numerical inputs but now I have started to use buttons I haven't managed to get it to work.

This is how I intended it to look with the data usage at the top:

[Variables displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS5ro.png)

And this is what I am getting with the buttons version (or not getting):

[Variables not displaying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSlza.png)

Missing the data usage parts

```
<h1>Data Usage Calculator</h1>
<p id="total_data_usage"></p>
<p id="total_monthly_data_usage"></p>
<style>
    .btn {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 8px 16px;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .btn.selected {
        background-color: black;
        color: white;
    }

    #total_data_usage {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    #total_monthly_data_usage {
        font-size: 40px;
    }

    body {
        padding: 20px;
        font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
        font-size: 13pt;
        text-align: center;
    }

    form {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 400px;
    }
</style>

<form>

    <h2>Select number of hours per day for streaming in SD:</h2>

    <button type="button" class="btn" id="never" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="0">Never</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="one_hour" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="1">1 hour</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="two_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="2">2 hours</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="three_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="3">3 hours</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="five_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="5">5 hours</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" id="eight_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="8">8 hours</button>

</form>

<script>

    document.getElementById("never").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
    document.getElementById("one_hour").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
    document.getElementById("two_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
    document.getElementById("three_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
    document.getElementById("five_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
    document.getElementById("eight_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);

</script>

<script>

    const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="sd_streaming_hours"]');

    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            // Deselect all buttons
            buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('selected'));
            // Select this button
            this.classList.add('selected');
        });
    });


</script>

<script>

    console.log(totalDataUsage);
    var totalDataUsage;
    var totalMonthlyDataUsage;

    function updateResult(event) {
        // Get the value of the clicked button
        var buttonValue = event.target.value;

        // Calculate the result of the desired calculation
        totalDataUsage = buttonValue * 2;

        // Display the result on the page
        document.getElementById("total_data_usage").innerHTML = totalDataUsage + "GB";
    }

</script>
```

I tried quite a lot of refinements but none of them seem to work. Everything seems to link back to the total_data_usage output but for some reason nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with your code. I cleaned it up by just separating the HTML/CSS/JS in the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) below, and it seems like everything works. (P.S. you should **absolutely** create an MRE *yourself* when you post a question like this.)

You will need to be more specific about what doesn't work when you run the example below.

```js
document.getElementById("never").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
document.getElementById("one_hour").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
document.getElementById("two_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
document.getElementById("three_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
document.getElementById("five_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);
document.getElementById("eight_hours").addEventListener("click", updateResult);

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button[name="sd_streaming_hours"]');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    // Deselect all buttons
    buttons.forEach(btn => btn.classList.remove('selected'));
    // Select this button
    this.classList.add('selected');
  });
});

console.log(totalDataUsage);
var totalDataUsage;
var totalMonthlyDataUsage;

function updateResult(event) {
  // Get the value of the clicked button
  var buttonValue = event.target.value;

  // Calculate the result of the desired calculation
  totalDataUsage = buttonValue * 2;

  // Display the result on the page
  document.getElementById("total_data_usage").innerHTML = totalDataUsage + "GB";
}
```

```css
.btn {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 8px 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn.selected {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

#total_data_usage {
  font-size: 40px;
}

#total_monthly_data_usage {
  font-size: 40px;
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13pt;
  text-align: center;
}

form {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Data Usage Calculator</h1>
<p id="total_data_usage"></p>
<p id="total_monthly_data_usage"></p>
<form>

  <h2>Select number of hours per day for streaming in SD:</h2>

  <button type="button" class="btn" id="never" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="0">Never</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="one_hour" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="1">1 hour</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="two_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="2">2 hours</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="three_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="3">3 hours</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="five_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="5">5 hours</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" id="eight_hours" name="sd_streaming_hours" value="8">8 hours</button>

</form>
```

Comment: Apologies, I have updated the original post with a couple of images to show expected and actual outcomes from the code.